# Assigning a hex number to IR branches in a Processor

Tags: assembly, x86, hex, processor, cpu-architecture

[image]

Can someone help me understand how I can assign each of the 5 IR branches to a hex number?

```
R[2] ← Mem2[R[1] + 0x5] << 0x02;

R[3] ← R[2]+ Mem2[0x0A] + 0x01;
```

With these two instructions, we should be able to assign a hex number to each of the five branches named IR<...>. I understand that the first branch on top is the only one directly related to the registry and the two bottom one will have constant values since they are not related to the registry. But can you guys help me or explain me how this syntax works?

Answer (score 0):

The block named "IR" in your picture is register with input (port D) width of 32 bit. So, its output (ports Q and ~Q) is 32 bit too.

The notation `IR<N1..N2>` means a part of 32 bits; e.g. `IR<12..0>` is for bits numbered 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12; and `IR<23..21>` means "take only bits 21,22,23,24".

So, if IR at some moment of time is binary: 00010010 00110100 01010110 01111000 (with bits numbered from end to start; 0x12345678 in hex); its parts are:

- `IR<31..24>` 8-bit wide value 0x12 = 00010010 - it will go to Control Circuit.
- `IR<23..21>` 3-bit wide value 0x1 = 001 - it will go to block "mux B", port 0 and to right part of register file (this is dst=destination register number)
- `IR<20..18>` 3-bit wide value 0x5 = 101 - it will go to block "mux B", port 1 (src1 or src2)
- `IR<17..15>` 3-bit wide value 0x0 = 000 - it will go to block "mux B", port 2 (src1 or src2)
- `IR<14..13>` 2-bit wide value 0x2 = 10 - to block "C"
- `IR<12..0>` 13-bit wide value 0x1678 = 10110 01111000 - to block "D" (this is IMM=immediate value)
- `IR<23..0>` is a copy of lower 24-bit = 0x345678 - to block "mux A" (in case of JMP command)

To solve your task we should know how commands are encoded into IR and what is the instruction set of this CPU. This looks like very simplified MIPS or RISC or may be SPARC.